# в основном why a в before the word?

Tags: грамматика

I tried to translate "mostly".

I just dont get the в before the word.

Is it something you add to indicate you're talking about a quantity that isn't compared to nothing else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composition-wise, ''в основном'' is like ''in general.'' The preposition ''в'' in ''в основном'' works just as the preposition ''in'' works in ''in general.'' I hope this analogy clarifies the issue.

Comment: Thanks!, It also explains why "I miss mostly the compliments" cant be translated with в основном.

Comment: @IbnRushd Actually you can say : Я не понимаю, в основном, комплименты. - in casual speech it sounds OK